# Get PropertyInfo value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the value from a `PropertyInfo[]`, but I can't get it to work:

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in foo.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null);
}
```

> Exception: `Object does not match target type.`

Isn't this how it's supposed to be done?

Comment: What type are `this` and `foo`?

Comment: Does `this` contain the property represented by `propertyInfo`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're trying to get properties from `this` when you originally fetched the `PropertyInfo`s from `foo.GetType()`. So this would be more appropriate:

```
var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(foo, null);
```

That's assuming you want to effectively get `foo.SomeProperty` etc.

Comment: @Johan: No, it refers to whatever object you're in the context of, just as normal... `propertyInfo` refers to each `propertyInfo` in the loop.

Answer (score 7):

You're getting that exception because `this` isn't the same type as `foo`.

You should make sure you're getting the properties for the same object that you're going to try to get the value from. I'm guessing from your code that you're expecting this to be foo inside the scope of the loop (which isn't the case at all), so you need to change the offending line to:

```
var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(foo, null);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are processing properties declared in `foo`'s type, but try to read their values from `this`, which apparently isn't of the same type.