# How to get datagrid row values in list

Tags: c#

This is my class that contains the row details for my `DataGrid`, 'calendarmstrDG'.

```
public class pojo
{
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Quarter { get; set; }
    public int SerialNo { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string PeriodName { get; set; }
}
```

I get the row data from the `DataGrid` using the code below:

```
var rowdata = calendarmstrDG.SelectedItem as pojo;
```

How do I convert the rowdata to a `List` of values?

Comment: var is just a shorthand syntax. The actual _type_ of that variable could be anything. In this case you're asserting (via the `as`) that it's a `pojo`. What is `pojo`? Is that the correct type? What is the type returned by the `SelectedItem` property of your calendar object?

Comment: `var` is not an `ArrayList`. It is an instance of `pojo` or `null`.

Comment: So obviously `var` will not be an `ArrayList` in this instance, what are you trying to make into an `ArrayList`? And why?

Comment: Then your question should be how to convert my class "pojo" to an array list, which doesnt make sense, the best suggestion i could make would be ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();    myAL.Add(rowdata)? its a confusing question at the moment

Comment: unless what you really want is calendarmstrDG.SelectedItems ???

Comment: I want to get all the row(from datagrid) details in a Arraylist..

Comment: calendarmstrDG is my datagrid name.
var rowdata = calendarmstrDG.SelectedItem as pojo
the output of this the above line is all the cell values of the first row (i am having only one row in my datagrid)

need to get all the first row details in a list..

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do here, don't use an `ArrayList` anymore, use a `List<pojo>`(and name your class `Pojo`)

Comment: so you want the columns of the row in an array?

Comment: Yes,exactly I want it in an array or list

Comment: @AvisSiva ok then you want to reword your question to one of the ones I suggested below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893028/c-sharp-foreach-property-in-object-is-there-a-simple-way-of-doing-this) and [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081193/get-propertyinfo-value).

Set `rowdata` as follows:

```
pojo rowdata = calendarmstrDG.SelectedItem as pojo;
```

Loop through the properties:

```
List<string> properties = new List<string>();

foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in rowdata.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   properties.Add(propertyInfo.GetValue(rowdata,null).ToString());
}
```

This should give you a `List<string>` containing your object property values, in string format.